# Has there been any discussion of implementing a privacy layer like zksnarks into EOS?

Tags: privacy

Ethereum seems to be in discussions of implementing zksnarks. Has there been any talks among EOS devs to integrate a privacy layer as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. Block.one is not working on implementing privacy at the protocol level as they're currently focused on scaling the blockchain vertically (i.e. through side chains)

[Confidential transactions](https://people.xiph.org/~greg/confidential_values.txt) (CT) could be implemented at the protocol level on eosio-based side-chains, but there has been no public announcement of anyone working on something like this as far as I know.

The standard practice right now is to store and send encrypted data to create a form of privacy, and there's a project called [privEOS](http://priveos.io/) that attempts to provide native functionality for this. However, this is limited to encrypting metadata and similar additional data, while sender, receiver, and amount of EOS transacted are all public.